# How to prevent font size in condition equation from getting changed

Tags: equations

Below is a snippet of my latex source that prints an equation. In the attached image output, I see a significant decrease in font size in the part of the equation that is represented as in the numerator/denominator form.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
        P[Y=l]=
        \begin{cases}
        \mu(lm+\mu)^{l-1}\frac{{e^{-lm-\mu}}}{r!(1-e^{-\mu})}}; & 1\leq l < M\\
        1-\sum_{s=1}^{M-1}\mu(sm+\mu)^{s-1}\frac{{e^{-sm-\mu}}}{s!(1-e^{-\mu})}; & l=M }\\
        \end{cases}
        \eqno{\hbox{(11)}}\\
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Can I force latex to print all parts of the equation in the same font size?

thanks

Comment: Yes. Use `\displaystyle\frac{}{}`

Comment: Your document produces the error `! Extra }, or forgotten $.` If you carry on after an error only use the resulting pdf for debugging purposes TeX does not attempt to produce reasonable output, just to get out of an error state

Comment: `\usepackage{mathtools}` in the preamble and `\begin{dcases}...\end{dcases}` instead of `cases`. ***Never*** use `\eqno` with LaTeX.